# Java Random параметр

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Здравствуйте, в приведенном ниже коде, не могу понять, почему при формировании объекта Random, в параметре указывается 47. Если я правильно понял, то в параметре указывается начальная точка последовательности случайных чисел. Но тогда почему на выводе числа которые меньше 47?

[image: foreach syntax]

Comment: потому что это текущий (читай предыдущий) элемент. И числа тут не меньше 47, грубо говоря генератор даёт целое число, которое потом делится на 2^BITS_COUNT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Random.next` возвращает по сути всегда целое число, вычисляемое по формуле

```
 (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)
```

Точная формула не столь важна, важно что новое  число зависит *только* от значения `seed`. Запомним это.

Конструктор принимает один параметр - `seed` (или вообще без параметра, тогда используется текущее время).

Этот `seed` будет использован для вычисления следующего числа, но сам он не будет возвращён в качестве случайного.

Теперь как вообще генерируются дробные числа.

Согласно документации

```
 public float nextFloat() {
   return next(24) / ((float)(1 << 24));
 }
```

Т.е. мы создаём целое число, обнуляем некоторое число бит, и делим на `2^24`. Вы можете получить любое число вида `N/2^24, 0<=N<2^24`. Это объясняет почему числа в диапазоне [0,1).